# Is it possible to send verification email and verifying the email before creating firebase user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to send verification email and verifying the email before creating firebase user? in my code I can only send email verification after calling the create user with email and password method from firebase. Even if I don't verify the email, I can still see an entry of that email in my firebase console.

Comment: Take a look at firebase cloud functions. I think you might need those

Answer (score 0):

User is created, but his email is marked as not verified, until he verifies it through email.

You can check that on the client, if the user have verified email or not and not allowing him to go next step until he verifies.

Check this blog: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html

Comment: Is it possible to enter the password after the email verification is completed?

Comment: You can use passwordless sign in that firebase is providing in email sign in and combine it with password sign in

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email to a user to verify their email address requires that the user is logged into Firebase already. So there's no way to require an email+password user to verify their email address before they can sign in.

You might want to have a look at Firebase's [email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) authentication provider, which sends an email to the provided email address, and clicking a link in that email then signs them in. In Flutter this flow start from the [`sendSignInLinkToEmail` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/sendSignInLinkToEmail.html).